# ModuleClient direct method connection stops working

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

A Direct method connector on azure-iot-edge module on raspberry pi 3 [armv7], will be available and I can make requests to it, however after a about 30min to a few hours the connection stops working.

I have rewritten the original module into smaller modules, so the logic for the connector is separate and very simple, also have written it using the dotnet sdk and nodejs sdk. Currently the iot edgeHub version is azureiotedge-hub:1.0.7

DotNet Version

```cs
static async Task Init()
{
    MqttTransportSettings mqttSetting = new MqttTransportSettings(TransportType.Mqtt_Tcp_Only);
    ITransportSettings[] settings = { mqttSetting };

    ModuleClient ioTHubModuleClient = await ModuleClient.CreateFromEnvironmentAsync(settings);
    await ioTHubModuleClient.OpenAsync();
    await ioTHubModuleClient.SetMethodHandlerAsync("powerset", DirectMethod1, ioTHubModuleClient);
}
```

NodeJs Version

```js
ModuleClient.fromEnvironment(Transport, function (err, client) {

 if (err) {
    console.log('error:' + err);
  } else {
  client.open(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('could not open IotHub client');
    } else {
      client.onMethod('powerset', function (request, response) {
        readMessage(client, request, response);
      });
    }
  });
}

}
```

What happens is these direct messages can be called when first deployed/started up, but soon they become unavailable. They either start to time out or start returning 'Not Found'.

Comment: Did you follow the checklist, especially for constrained devices like the Raspi? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/production-checklist#dont-optimize-for-performance-on-constrained-devices

Comment: Half. Did set the OptimizeForPerformance to false and I'm not using the debug. Have not yet disabled unused protocols [http and amqp] or reduced storage time for messages[2 hours]. Will do both.

Comment: Removing unused protocols and dropping reduced storage, sorted it! Been running for 2 days now with no issues.Thanks silent!